# Bounded set in $(P_p(\mathbb{R}^d),W_p(\cdot,\cdot))$ is precompact?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimal-transport

Does the Wasserstein space $(P_p(\mathbb{R}^d),W_p(\cdot,\cdot))$ posesses the property that any bounded set is precompact? Or at least, if $\mu_0\in P_p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and given $r>0$ a real number, is the Wasserstein ball $B(\mu_0,r):=\{\mu\in P(\mathbb{R}^d) : W_p(\mu_0,\mu)<r\}$ a [tight set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures)?

Comment: I personally think the former statement is false, since the Wasserstein space should be an infinite dimensional Banach space, which wouldn't have the Heine-Borel property. I don't think the second is true as well for a similar reason, although I'd of course need some time to verify this. But what is your source for this question? And have you thought about what happens if you replace $\mathbb R^d$ by a finite set, like $\{0,1\}$ or something? It could be helpful.

Comment: I have no source really, I don't know if it is true or false but the result would help me to conclude a proof

Comment: In the search for context,it'd be helpful if you briefly mentioned (a) What property/theorem are you trying to prove and why is this piece of the puzzle important there? (you can avoid this if it is a research problem, but if it's a problem from a textbook/paper/PDF then you can reveal it) (b) What are your thoughts on what I wrote? (about infinite Banach spaces/ replacing $\mathbb R^d$ by a finite set) (c) What is your level of expertise? (As in, how much do you know in probability theory?) Answers to these questions if clear can be added to the post and I will be at your service.

Comment: All these are being done to prevent future closure of your question, and also for me to see if I can consult sources regarding your "bigger" problem / look up good sources for you / give you further ideas on what you can do when you hit this kind of a question. If your problem is a long-pending one  I can attempt to look it up if you wish as well, although I can't answer it as it is not the primary requirement of the post.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, it is a Banach space when you consider the norm $\|\mu\|_p=W_p(0,\mu)$? And this is indeed a norm since the Wasserstein metric is translational invariant because $W_p(\mu+\theta,\nu+\theta)=\max\limits_{u\in Lip_1}\{\int u d\mu+\theta-\nu-\theta\}=W(\mu,\nu)$ by duality, is then you use the result that any infinite dimensional Banach space doesn't have the Heine-Borel property?

Comment: Correct, that's kind of what I mean, @roi_saumon : an infinite dimensional Banach space doesn't have the HB property, and you seem to have demonstrated that the space here is an infinite dimensional Banach space.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I could show that Wasserstein balls with center in $\mu_0\in P_p$ are tight. However, by your argument, these balls are not compact (right?), so we should be able to find a sequence in the ball such that $\mu_n\rightharpoonup \mu$ (narrow convergence) but such that $\mu_n\not\xrightarrow{W_p} \mu$. Can you think of any?

Comment: Sure, I'll think and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Wasserstein space does not have the property that bounded sets are precompact. A counterexample is given in Remark 2.8 here: [https://www.math.umd.edu/~yanir/OT/AmbrosioGigliDec2011.pdf](https://www.math.umd.edu/%7Eyanir/OT/AmbrosioGigliDec2011.pdf). The preceding theorem also gives a characterization of precompactness in $W_2$ ($W_p$ is very similar).

PS. I do not agree that $W_p (0, \mu)$ is a norm, at least in the obvious way. After all, given a constant $c\neq 0$, we would require that $\Vert c \mu \Vert_p = |c| \Vert \mu \Vert_p$. But what is $c \mu$ supposed to be? Usually in measure theory we would say that $c \mu$ is defined so that $ c\mu(A) = c (\mu(A))$ for every measurable set. But if $c\neq1$ then $c\mu$ is not even a probability measure, hence not even in $W_p$, so $W_p (0, c\mu)$ is ill-defined.

However, $W_p (\mathbb(R)^d)$ is a complete separable metric space which is in some sense infinite-dimensional. It is just not a Banach space. It is better to think of the space of probability measures as a surface inside the space of all signed measures (which is actually a Banach space), but with $W_p$ we have equipped that surface with an exotic metric that is not induced from the ambient space.